# How to make a link to "current category page" on product page in M2

Tags: magento2

How can I create a link on "product page" to the "category page" a product is assigned?

Jesper

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121006/how-to-get-product-current-category-name-in-magento-2-in-product-view-page
this answer can help you.
by @Suresh Chikani

Answer (score 1):

A product can be assigned to many categories so this can a challenge.

Just a quick approach; create a product attribute and assign the necessary information and display it in the theme.

Answer (score 1):

There are no simple answers in Magento but to get the url in a template file heres the 'dirty' way

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$currentCategory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
echo $currentCategory->getUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working, with objectmanager.

Is there a better way to do it?

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
foreach($categories as $category){
    $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
    }
?>

Se alle <a href="<?php echo $cat->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $cat->getName(); ?></a>
```

Comment: this code loops through all assigned categories and adds a link to the last category the current product is assigned to not the category the user came from before they arrived on the product page (as per the question).

Answer (score 0):

**Using Current Category :-**

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');

  <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $category->getName(); ?></a>
```